# Error handling middleware - converting err to string for response

Tags: go

I have this middleware func:

```
func errorMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer func() {
            if err := recover(); err != nil {
                log.Error("Caught error in defer/recover middleware: ", err)
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
                json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(struct {
                    ID string
                }{
                    err.Error(),
                })
            }
        }()
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

I use it like so:

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.Use(errorMiddleware)
```

however I am getting a compilation error, it says:

[image]

Anybody know what that's about? I am just trying to convert err to a string, ultimately, serialize it for the client etc.

Answer (score 3):

`recover()` returns an interface with no methods to proxy any value sent by `panic()`. In the defer block, you're trying to access the `Error()` method of a pure, has-no-method interface. If you want to distinguish the built-in error type, you'd have to assert its type like:

```
realErr, ok := err.(error)
if ok {
    // here you can use realErr.Error().
}
```

So that it'll give you a real value of type `error`. If you check out the [built-in types](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error), you'll see that `error` is to implement an `Error() string` method.

Type assertions: https://tour.golang.org/methods/15